I am unable to load an image from url in my electron app
I'm using Electron with create-electron-app with Webpack template along with React and Tailwind.
I'm trying to load an image from URL like this "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/C2QCuBX_byg/maxresdefault.jpg" in the image tag. The app keeps showing CSP warnings and the image does not load.
I tried to add CSP rules to allow img-src from i.ytimg.com, but still it shows the same error like this:
Refused to load the image 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/C2QCuBX_byg/maxresdefault.jpg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I thought that Electron could load images like a browser from an image URL ending with .jpg. Is it possible to fix this and load images from URL on the electron?
